# VBA Runtime 52 Error When Creating Sub Directory

Tags: excel, vba, subdirectory

I keep getting runtime errors when I try to create a subdirectory using this code.  Right now it is 52 runtime error.

```
Sub CreateFolder(DateExt As String)
   Dim Pth As String, NewFldr As String, NewDir As String

   Pth = ActiveWorkbook.Path
   NewFldr = "/" & DateExt & " IDR Statements"
   NewDir = Pth & NewFldr
    If Dir(NewDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
      MkDir NewDir
    End If

End Sub
```

I suppose it is worth noting that this is on a shared network drive.

I tried altering the syntax many different ways and sometimes got a 72 runtime error.  But the way the code is currently written I get the 52 runtime error.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/bad-file-name-or-number-error-52

Comment: What is `Pth`,  seems null?   Your folder name has issues.  Try removing the leading `/`.

Comment: Is the `ActiveWorkbook` saved?  Does `DateExt` contain any characters not allowed in a folder name?

Comment: Pth is not null.  When it stops running at the "If" statement Pth contains the file path of the document I am in.  I tried removing the / but that didn't change anything.

Comment: The ActiveWorkbook is saved.  DateExt is 2023-08-28 when it gets to the break point

Comment: Does it matter that this is on a shared drive that is working through sharepoint?